# C#, I want to call a method with parameters like var test = new test1.test2.Method("parameter1","parameter2")

Tags: c#, class

I want to call a method in a fixed structure like below in C#:

```
var Test = new test1.test2.test3("parameter1","parameter2");
```

Is this possible in C#?

Here test1 and test2 can be classes and test3 is my method name and it will return string text.

I can manage if need to remove new keyword.

I am assuming it should something like this :-

```
Public class test1
{
   Public class test2
   {
     Public string test3("parameter1","parameter2")
     {
       //Do something
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: That could can mean several things. It could be a type test3 in the namespace test1.test2, or it can be a type test1 with a public property test2 of a type that has a public property test3. Its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: This question is so vague. However, you don't use `new` with method calls.

Comment: What is test1,test2 and test3 ? What are you exactly trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @cvraman, here  test1 can be a namespace or class and test2 is class name and test3 is method name, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can if test3 is public structure type nested inside public structure type test2 which is nested inside test1

```
struct test1{
    public struct test2{
        public struct test3{
            public test3(string p1,string p2) {/*do something*/}
            //some params
        }
        //some params
    //some params
}
```

Also test1 and test2 could be namespaces.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Yes test1 can be name space or class name, but I want to prefer class instead of struct. Can we can do something like this using class? I can manage if need to remove  new keyword.

Comment: Same thing goes with classes. But in either of cases you can't remove 'new' keyword because you create a new test3 struct, which uses 2 params in constructor. If test3 is not a struct, but a static method inside test2 it is called without 'new'.

Comment: Is a simple static method what you're looking for?

Comment: @Baldrick, That what I am looking for, what I need to do to create test1 and test2? and test3 will be method inside test2.

Comment: If it is a static method you have no need in creation of test1 and test2